# C - Can I define a default function pointer in a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    void(*func)(struct Point*, int);
};

void addToX(struct Point* a, int b) {
    a->x += b;
}

void main() {
    struct Point p1;
    p1.x = 3;
    p1.func = &addToX;

    printf("%d\n", p1.x);

    p1.func(&p1, 2);
    printf("%d\n", p1.x);
}
```

In the code above, we have an object `Point`, which contains `x` and a function.

When I'm making a `Point`, I need to initialize `x` and the pointer to the function.

This is pretty bad as I don't want to initialize the function pointer every time!

Is there a way to define it, so that every time I create a new Point it will automatically point to `addToX`?

Comment: Why not `struct Point p1 = {3, &addToX};`? You can also make a C++-style point generator `Point* makePoint(int val);` that creates a new struct and initializes its fields.

Comment: @valdo this is for uni project, can't use c++.

Comment: @DYZ it's repetitive + someone might point it to other function later in mistake.

Comment: @daniel Look at the second part of my comment.

Comment: The details: `void main() {...}` -->> `int main(void) {...}` /nitpick

Comment: You can just initialise it as any other `struct`:  `struct Point p1 = {3, addToX};`.  Note that the `&` is redundant.

Comment: @wildplasser:  should that not be `// nitpick`?

Comment: If you're always using the same function, why does it need to be in the struct in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have some default values, you need to create constructor function. Something like this:

```
struct Point createPoint(int x) {
    struct Point r = { x, addToX };
    return r;
}
```

And then just use it like this:

```
struct Point p1 = createPoint(3);
```

---

Alternatively, you could create default value as a macro:

```
#define POINT_INITIALIZER(x) { (x), addToX }
```

Used like:

```
struct Point p1 = POINT_INITIALIZER(3);
```

---

I would recommend function, because they are more safe, and I don't see any advantage the macro would give.

Comment: seems like the most elegant way to solve this as its 1 line and does not require to initialize anything. i'm talking about the first option ofc

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it is to have a default struct that you can copy.

```
const struct​ foo default_foo = {
    .func = myfunc;
};
```

Later you can just initialize a new struct foo to the default.

```
struct foo local_foo = default_foo;
```

You could even have other versions for common use cases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the answers to your problem are called **class** and **C++**. Is there any particular reason you are sticking to plain C?

EDIT:
Since you said it's for an uni project: no, you cannot initialize it "automatically". The best solution I could think of is to define something like:

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    void(*func)(struct Point*, int);
};

void addToX(struct Point*a, int b) {
    a->x +=b;
}

void point_init(struct Point* a) {
    a->func = &addToX;
}

void main() {
    struct Point p1;
    point_init(&p1);
    p1.x = 3;

    printf("%d\n", p1.x);

    p1.func(&p1, 2);
    printf("%d\n", p1.x);
}
```